# Ruby Curb gem - Ubiquiti mPower HTTP API

Tags: ruby, http, curl, curb

I am attempting to replicate [this](http://community.ubnt.com/t5/mFi/mPower-mFi-Switch-and-mFi-In-Wall-Outlet-HTTP-API/m-p/1076449#U1076449) HTTP API for Ubiquiti's mPower units using the [Curb gem](https://github.com/taf2/curb) and store the output from this into a CSV file.

**Using cURL:**

```
curl -X POST -d "username=user&password=pass" -b "AIROS_SESSIONID=01234567890123456789012345678901" 192.168.1.75/login.cgi

curl -b "AIROS_SESSIONID=01234567890123456789012345678901" 192.168.1.75/sensors/1/power
```

Returns:

```
{"sensors":[{"power":2.740736961}],"status":"success"}
```

**My attempt using Curb:**

```
require 'curb'    

cookie = rand(36**32).to_s(36)

curl = Curl::Easy.new('http://192.168.1.75/login.cgi')

curl.http_post(
  Curl::PostField.content('username', 'user'),
  Curl::PostField.content('password', 'pass'))

curl = Curl::Easy.new('http://192.168.1.75/sensors/1/power')
curl.cookies = cookie
curl.perform
```

Adding `puts curl.perform` to the end of the script prints `true`.

Using cURL, I can usually pull the data with a delay ranging from 1-3 seconds from the time I execute `curl -b...` from the command line before the response shows up. How can I achieve the same results using Curb and save **only** the power data to a local variable? Is there a better tool to accomplish this task besides Curb?

Answer (score 0):

I would parse the results using the `JSON` module.

```
require 'curb'
require 'json'

curl = Curl::Easy.new('http://192.168.1.75/login.cgi')
curl.cookies = "AIROS_SESSIONID=#{rand(36**32).to_s(36)}"

curl.http_post(
  Curl::PostField.content('username', 'user'),
  Curl::PostField.content('password', 'pass'))

curl.url = 'http://192.168.1.75/sensors/1/power'
curl.perform

result_hash = JSON.parse(curl.body_str)
power = result_hash["sensors"][0]["power"] #=> should get 2.740736961
```

Can't test it because I don't have your API implemented, but this should work if the response is exactly as you showed up there..

Comment: I am receiving the error undefined method `undefined method []` . Also when I put the contents of `curl.body_str` I get `{"status":"fail"}`. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Hmm not sure.. what if you replace the cookies line with `curl.cookies = "AIROS_SESSIONID=01234567890123456789012345678901"`?